# What tag style should we follow for AWS products/services?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

As of now, both the `aws-*` and `amazon-*` version of the tags are synonyms for each other.

So, which one of them should we have as the master?

Do we want the `aws-*` style tag or the `amazon-*` style tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The master tag should be the official service name

For example, [aws-lambda](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws-lambda) is the correct tag, because the [product name is AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) (and, not to mention, [everyone calls it AWS Lambda](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=AWS%20Lambda,Amazon%20Lambda)).

- [amazon-ec2](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) should be the master because [that's the official name](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).
- [amazon-cloudwatch](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudwatch) should be the master because [that's the product name](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/).
- [amazon-s3](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3) should be the master (see [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)).
- [amazon-ami](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ami) should be [amazon-machine-images](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-machine-images) (see [Amazon Machine Images](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)—Amazon AMI is a litlte redundant!)
- [aws-cli](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws-cli) should be the master (see [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/))
- [aws-codedeploy](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws-codedeploy) should be the master (see [AWS CodeDeploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html))
- [amazon-api-gateway](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-api-gateway) should be master (see [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)).
- [aws-kms](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws-kms) should be master (see [AWS Key Management Service](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/))

As a general rule, most of the products are [amazon-*], except CLI, CodeDeploy, KMS and Lambda. Let me know if I've missed any, though.

Comment: Completely agree, it's hard to remember which ones are 'Amazon' and which are 'AWS' but we should be consistent.

Comment: I think [tag:amazon-cloudwatch] is resolving in the wrong direction, it appears to be resolving to [tag:aws-cloudwatch].

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with creating aliases for all of them so it gets automatically canonicalized by the site?

Comment: @chicks Yes, I think the idea here is for both tags to be synonymised—I intended to discuss which tag should be the 'master' (the tag that should the 'canonical' one). Is that what you're wondering about, or something else?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that we were keeping the aliases, but rereading the question the context is more obvious.